# jasmine-node, pass just one spec file as argument

Tags: node.js, jasmine, jasmine-node

```
require('jasmine-node')

describe( "hello world", function() {
  it( "a simple app", function(){
    expect("1").toEqual("1")
    console.log("this is a simpler application")
  });
});
```

I am trying to run the above helloworld program using `jasmine-node`. But it is not running any tests and shows message as,

```
0 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 skipped
```

I am not keen on using a configuration file for just one spec file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to set a variable equal to the `require()`. For example,

```
var jasmineNode = require( "jasmine-node" );
```

But you don't have to require Jasmine in order to use it. I just deleted the first line (the `require()` statement) and then ran `jasmine-node` on the file

```
jasmine-node hello.spec.js
```

and it worked.

```
this is a simpler application
.

Finished in 0.007 seconds
1 test, 1 assertion, 0 failures, 0 skipped
```

Note that to use `jasmine-node` this way, you have to have installed it globally with

```
npm install jasmine-node -g
```